NGINX - rewrite uri using regex instead of variables
I am attempting to rewrite incoming uri requests to http://core/api/token to simply http://token. I have tried successfully to do this by specifying variables in the location block:
rewrite ${INBOUND_ENDPOINT} ${REDIRECT_ENDPOINT} break;

BUT I have been asked to use regex in an if statement to just take the last part of any incoming uri to just use the last part, in this case /token.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.
Update:
I tried to use something like this and had no luck either:
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com;

  # Handle favicon.ico requests separately to prevent unwanted redirects
  location = /favicon.ico {
    return 204;
  }

  location / {
    # Use an if statement to match and capture the final part of the path
    if ($request_uri ~* ^.*/([^/]+)$) {
      # Rewrite the URI to use only the final part of the path
      set $final_part $1;
      rewrite ^ /$final_part break;
    }
  }
}


I tried to use something like this and had no luck either....
`server {
listen 80;
server_name example.com;
# Handle favicon.ico requests separately to prevent unwanted redirects
location = /favicon.ico {
    return 204;
}

location / {
    # Use an if statement to match and capture the final part of the path
    if ($request_uri ~* ^.*/([^/]+)$) {
        # Rewrite the URI to use only the final part of the path
        set $final_part $1;
        rewrite ^ /$final_part break;
    }
}

}`
